# Whats the best way to load an HTML select with JQuery from C# WCF?

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

I know at least 1 long way to do it, but I figured I might as well ask.

I have a bunch of values in a C# WCF Service (I could make it into an array, dictionary, etc)

**I would like to make an AJAX call from JQuery that will consume the service and load the html select.**

I was thinking of returning an IEnumerable from the WCF service, and loop through them in JQuery, adding s to my select.

Is there a better way to do this?

Is there some JQuery command that will consume an array-like structure from WCF and load the box for me? I'm not looking for AJAX code, only JQuery code to load the select, and a recommendation of types to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery templating 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/

Comment: ah, yes, that probably is the cleanest.  Didn't know why I didn't think of it in this case..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this would do pretty much what I've explained.  Is it the best way?

http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/23/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-using-jquery-and-ajax/